# Running an initialize Parse function inside of an AngularJS module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-module

I've read that a good way to initialize Parse is when the module is created. I made the following code, however Parse does not seem to be initializing when I run my program. Am I missing something basic about setting up run functions on a module?

Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    })
    .run(function($rootScope) {
        Parse.initialize("myKey", "myKey");
        $rootScope.sessionUser = Parse.User.current();
    });
```

Comment: Did you include the parse script within your html?  If so, prior to your angular app? <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.9.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes. I have the parse script in my header and the module is in the body.